# Get ./configure line from Debian Package

Tags: debian, package-management

I want to build the source of a package on myself (new version, some additions) but I want to use the `./configure` options from the original package as a starting point. I can't find anything in the source package, so where can I see the actual options used to compile a binary Debian package?

The Name of the package is `php5-cgi`.

Comment: What is the name of the package?

Comment: I've added the name in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The options should be in the source package in the `debian/rules` file.

You can also check the build log, to see how exactly the package was built.
Search for the package on https://buildd.debian.org/status/package.php
Follow the links to the version you want to check and click on the result to see the full log file and search for `./configure`.

Comment: Great! But I can't find php5-cgi with the search :(

Comment: `php5-cgi` is a sub-package (unsure if this is the correct term) of the `php5` package. You can figure this out by searching for the package on http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php5-cgi and follow the "Developer Information" link on the right hand side. Note: since it's using sub-packages there might be multiple `./configure` calls in the log.